# gwt RequestFactory Map containing a List

Tags: java, list, dictionary, gwt, requestfactory

I want to use a `Map<enum, List<Integer>>` in a gwt RequestFactory. (I'm using gwt-2.7.0)

According to the [latest documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html#transportable) (which still seems to be for version 2.7.0) this should work.

> `Map` where `K` and `V` are transportable types

both K (enum) and V *are* transportable types.

However, when I run the RequestFactory ValidationTool, I get the following error:

```
The type java.util.Map<com.example.MyEnum ,java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>> cannot be used here
```

Note, `Map<enum, Integer>` does work.

Am I missing something here or is it just not possible?

I couldn't find any answers on google, except for old versions were Maps were not supported at all.
I can't believe no one else had this problem since they introduced Maps.

Any workarounds or do I really have to wrap this Map?

Comment: Does it work with `Map<String, List<Integer>>`? You can try by calling `enum.name()` to get the key.

Comment: @Baz nope, doesn't work either: `error: The type java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>> cannot be used here`

Comment: [This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/aLcp95-jhcI) seems related and seems to suggest that: _"nested parameterized types still aren't supported"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This still doesn't seem to be supported. There's an open issue on GitHub:

[RequestFactory support for nested parameterizations](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/5973).

Comments suggest wrapping your inner type in a POJO:

```
public class MyObject {
    private List<Integer> list;
}
```

and the using

```
Map<MyEnum, MyObject>
```